# Having issue with 1NF in normalisation

Tags: database, normalization

I am a little bit confused when doing normalisation for repeating and non repeating data. Look at fields below:

Option_Table:

```
OptionId (PK auto) OptionType
1                  A-C
2                  A-D
3                  A-E
```

Question:

```
QuestionId (PK auto) OptionId
1                    3
2                    2
3                    2
```

If you look at table above, tchnically OptionType is not repeating and OptionId is repeating but it is a forign key so I am assuming it is still ok to state `OptionId` is non-repeating in first normal form. But for `OptionType` it looks like non repeating data but it is not a key, just a normal field, so is below correct or incorrect:

Repeating:

None

Non - Repeating:

**QuestionId**, **OptionId**, Option Type

Bold means it is a key. Can I simply pick and choose which non repeating data can and cannot be keys?

Answer (score 0):

Repeating and non-repeating don't refer to rows.  They refer to columns within a row.

If your OptionType column is to be interpreted as follows: A-C means A, B, C and so forth, then there is an argument to say that OptionType is a repeating column.  There is also an argument to say that it is a range, not a repeating column, however, in that case you would be much better off with the lower and upper bounds of the range in separate columns.

Comment: Sooo ... , am I ok as stating it as I have done or does it need to change (the normalisation I am referring to)

Comment: @Manixman - It's not possible for me to say.  I don't know what you mean by Option Type.  Is it "A-C", "A-D" and so on?  If so, then you have to look at the semantics and decide if this is a range or a short-hand for discrete values.  If it is a range then you should at the very least divide it into two range ends.  If it is a short-hand for discrete values then you should probably normalize it out.  Normalization depends on semantics.  You can't make a decision about how to normalize a relation without understanding what the data means.

Comment: What I mean is that is how the table tables are definetl set out. With the table set out as that, then is my normalisation (1NF) correct the example of them two tables. That is all I am asking

Comment: What I mean is that is how the  tables are definetly set out. With the tables set out as that, then is my normalisation (1NF) correct the example of them two tables. That is all I am asking

Comment: @Manixman - I understand your question, but I can't answer it because looking at a list of column names isn't enough to tell whether something is normalized to any given normal form.  Column names only give a hint, they don't explain exactly what data goes in each column and most importantly, what that data means.  Nobody can answer your question as you have asked it.  You need to be much clearer about what tables you are proposing for 1NF and what data goes in each column.